# Recursive Return Statement

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, return

This is a program that I have wrote to solve a problem. Check if there exists a sum of elements that equal to the maximum number in the array, return true if so, false otherwise.

```
var found = "false";
var max;

function ArrayAdditionI(array) { 

max = Math.max.apply(null,array);
var p = array.indexOf(max);

array.splice(p,1);
array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b;});


found = findSum(array, 0, 0);

return found;

}

function findSum(array, sum, startIndex){

for(var i = startIndex; i < array.length ; i++){

    sum += array[i]; 

    if(sum === max){
        found = "true";
        break;
    }else if(sum > max){
        break;
    }

     if(i+2 < array.length && sum < max){
         findSum(array, sum, i+2);
    }

}
    if(startIndex < array.length && sum !== max){
        return findSum(array, 0, startIndex+1);
    }

    return found;
}

ArrayAdditionI(readline());
```

I had to use global variable, found, to indicate where a sum has been found or not. The return statement always returned undefined.

Also, if I use a return statement in the following if statement, the code does not work properly.

```
if(i+2 < array.length && sum < max){
    return findSum(array, sum, i+2);
}
```

This is not the optimal solution to the problem, but this is the version I got working.

My question is Why am I getting undefined if I use return statement within the if statement. Also, I tried not using global and use return true if sum === max and at the very end return false, it always returns false or undefined.

-- UPDATE 2: Code with error results --

```
function ArrayAdditionI(array) { 
    var max = Math.max.apply(null,array);

    //remove max element from array
    var p = array.indexOf(max);
    array.splice(p,1);

    //sort array
    array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b;});

    //call find sum function
    return findSum(array, 0, 0, max);

}

function findSum(array, sum, startIndex){
    for(var i = startIndex; i < array.length ; i++){

        sum += array[i];

        if(sum === max){
            return true;
        }else if(sum > max){
            break;
        }

        if(i+2 < array.length && sum < max){
            **return** findSum(array, sum, i+2, max);
        }

    }
    if(startIndex < array.length && sum !== max){
        return findSum(array, 0, startIndex+1, max);
    }

    return false;
}

// calling the first function
ArrayAdditionI([  7, 2,90, 31, 50 ]);
```

The start of the program is this call: ArrayAdditionI([  7, 2,90, 31, 50 ]); 
The return should be true. 
Also, ArrayAdditionI([  1,2,3,4 ]); is true.
However, ArrayAdditionI([  1,2,3,100 ]); is false.

The return statement between ** **, when removed the code works, otherwise I either get false or undefined. I do not understand this part! Why does removing the return solves the problem, I thought every recursive call must be proceeded with a return statement.

Is the problem maybe due to multiple calls ? Am I using recursion in the improper way?

Comment: What's the question? How not to use a global? How better to solve the problem?

Comment: Side note: Don't use strings for booleans. Use booleans for booleans. :-) E.g., `found = false` (not `found = "false"`), `found = true` (not `found = "true"`), `if (found)` (not `if (found == "true")`)...

Comment: My question is Why am I getting undefined if I use return statement within the if statement. Also, I tried not using global and use return true if sum === max and at the very end return false, it always returns false or undefined.

Comment: Do you need this to do a sum for any combination of elements or just any two elements? If so, I will edit my question.

Comment: Any number of elements

Comment: The maximum number of course is not included

Comment: Yikes, even with an array of just 10 items, there are a lot of permutations. Does anybody know how to calculate the maximum number of permutations given an array of n length?

Comment: I updated my answer with code to handle any combination of elements.

Comment: Last question... does it absolutely have to be recursive? The function I posted does what is asked and does not need to be.

Comment: Well it doesn't. I just don't understand why my recursion solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The following function should give you a true or false answer as to whether or not any combination of values inside an array produces the max figure.

```
    var a = [
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 9
    ]
    var b = [1,1,1,5]
    function MembersHoldMaxSum(arr) {
        var i, r = false, index, max = Math.max.apply(null, arr), index;
        for (i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (index = 0; index <= arr.length - 1; index++) {
                var new_arr = [], ct;
                for (ct = 0; ct <= arr.length - 1; ct++) {
                    if (index != ct) { new_arr.push(arr[ct]) }
                }
                while (new_arr.length != 1) {
                    var sum = 0, ct2 = 0;
                    for (ct2 = 0; ct2 <= new_arr.length - 1; ct2++) {
                        sum += new_arr[ct2];
                    }
                    if (sum == max) { return true }
                    new_arr.pop()
                }
            }
        }
        return r
    }
    var returns_true = MembersHoldMaxSum(a);
    var returns_false = MembersHoldMaxSum(b);
```

Comment: @Maryam Please do not forget about this question. It took quite some legwork for me to create a working example for you. When you have a moment, please click the green check mark on the question so to accept the answer. This gives both you and I additional reputation points. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes on your code that could lead to the error.

T.J. Crowder already said, use actual booleans instead of a string.

The `found` variable isn't defined inside your `findSum` function. That makes JavaScript assume you're setting a global variable.
Add `var found = false;` as the very first line of your `findSum` function.

Inside the last `if` inside your `for` there are a call to the `findSum` function but it's not returning it's value nor assigning it to the `found` variable.

Fix those and update your question with the results.

Comment: Found is a global variable. If I use a return statement I get undefined. The above code is working. I was just wondering why the recursion & return statements aren't working. I had to add global variable as a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I give up on trying to understand how your code is working and what else you want. You're assigning the `found` var sometimes and sometimes you're returning the value instead.

Comment: It's defined at the very top. var found = false. There are two functions, array addition, which is called first, and take an array as an input *see the last line*, and the second function find sum that checks if a sum exists.

Comment: When I call the function recursively inside the if statement with a return, I get undefined, with return false. I'll post my code which doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my question with the old code. It doesn't give the correct result.